# MediaPlayer android, playing a file that's is inside the project

Tags: android, android-emulator

i'm a new android dev. Actually i'm moving from iPhone to Android :-)

well, i'm modifying the source of one of the examples (MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java) here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/index.html

well, the point is that i want to play a video that is inside the project.

my questions:

1. where should i place the video file?, i guess inside the assets folder.
2. how do i get the correct video file path?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop the file in the res/raw folder. Then the next time you compile you'll get a new entry in the gen R.java file. This lovely file contains references to all your resources; strings, images, etc.

Then use the MediaPlayer class to play the file from the resource, using the resource ID that was generated for you. e.g.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.my_video_file);
```

In your example you can probably replace 'context' with 'this'.

You don't ever need to know the actual file path, its probably not exposed to you anyway.

Have a look at these bits of documentation for more info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! You made the best to choose android :)

Yes you can put any file in asset folder.

For the path: R.asset.name